# Clicking Export to Excel button using Selenium automation navigates to error page

Tags: html, excel, vba, selenium-webdriver

I am using the SeleniumBasic wrapper for VBA and have created a script that uses Chrome to automate logging into a website, selecting a few relevant options, then downloading the results to an .xlsx by clicking a button that says Export to Excel, shown in 1st picture.

[image: Options Page]

The problem is that if the script clicks the button, it will open an error page as shown in 2nd picture.  If the button is clicked manually, it downloads the file normally.

[image: Error Page]

I'm not sure if it is relevant, but I noticed that the button is an input element rather than a button element.  This picture shows other elements that encapsulate it as well.

[image: HTML]

Parts of my script here:

```
    bot.Start "chrome", sURL
    bot.Get "/"
    bot.Window.Maximize
```

Further down...

```
    Set elmSkillBox = bot.FindElementById("TWMS_content_rlbAvailable")
    Set elmInclude = bot.FindElementById("TWMS_content_rlbInclude")
    Set elmCheck = bot.FindElementById("content_chkEmptyEmployees")
    Set elmExport = bot.FindElementById("content_btnExcel")
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(vSkills)
        Set elmSkill = bot.FindElementByXPath("//*[contains(text(), '" & vSkills(i) & "')]")
        bot.Actions.DragAndDrop(elmSkill, elmInclude).Perform

        bot.Wait 1000
    Next i

    If elmCheck.IsSelected Then elmCheck.Click
    
    bot.Wait 1000
```

I've tried both of these methods to avoid the error page:

```
    bot.Actions.MoveToElement(elmExport).Perform
    bot.Actions.Click(elmExport).Perform
```

And...

```
    elmExport.Click
```

Comment: As this is an input button you need to use `elmExport.submit`